# Text alignment error in table with figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, vertical-alignment

This picture illustrates the problem:

[image]

Why does the text end up below the figure? I've tried searching extensively for ways to align it to the top but every guide assumes it is aligned to the top by default...

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
    \tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
    \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
    \subsection{Flowchart}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{6cm}|p{6cm}|  }
        \hline
        Algorithm & Flowchart\\
        \hline
        Stuff 
        
        more
        
        stuff
        & 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
        \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
        \node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Input};
        \node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {Loop start};
        \node (pro2) [process, below of=pro1] {Process 1};
        \node (pro3) [process, below of=pro2] {Process 1};
        \node (dec1) [decision, below of=pro3] {Decision 1};
        
        \draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
        \draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
        \draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (pro2);
        \draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro3);
        \draw [arrow] (pro3) -- (dec1);
        
        \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=north] {Yes} ([xshift=7mm] dec1.east) -- ([xshift=7mm] pro1.east) -- (pro1);
        \end{tikzpicture} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How do I fix this? I just want any way to make it be readable. Thanks

Comment: Which alignment do you want? At top? Centred?

Comment: I you want horizontal centering, be sure to load the `array` package and change `p{6cm}` to `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{6cm}`.

Comment: Either top or centred is fine

Comment: Please tell us how you enter "Stuff more stuff".

Comment: Could you add the preamble, so the code is compilable?

Comment: it _always_ helps if you provide a complete test document not just a fragment.  the layout you show is expected as you have two `p` columns so they align on the baseline of their first rows, so the baseline of the text on the left aligns with the reference point of the tikzpicture which is its bottom edge by default

Comment: To change the baseline of the tikzpicture from its bottom edge to its top edge, you could add `baseline=(current bounding box.north)`.

Comment: Depending on the actual contents of the "Algorithm"  column (literally just text or some kind of pseudocode using one of the dedicated packages?), an entirely different appraoch, probably based on two side by side minipages might result in a better looking output. Therefore, please clarify what kind of contents the first column should contain and how they should look like.

Comment: Added MWE and clarification

Comment: Alright, the baseline=(current bounding box.north) solved it, thanks!

Comment: Since you used the deprecated `\tikzstyle` in your MWE: You might want to consider switching to `\tikzstyle` for globally defined styles or just define them in the options of your `tikzpicture` if you only want to use these styles locally.

Comment: Ok thanks, this isn't a mission critical doc so I'll get by with deprecated code for now. Will research how to do it the correct way later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding `baseline=(current bounding box.north)` to the options of the `tikzpicture`, you can shift its baseline from the default bottom edge to its top edge. This however will result in the top of the tikzpicture being vertically aligned with the bottom of the first line of text:

[image]

To overcome this, I measured the height of the letter S using `\settoheight{\mylength}{S}` and stored that value in `\mylength`. We can now use `baseline={([yshift=-\mylength]current bounding box.north)}` in order to shift the baseline of the `tkizpicture` down by the height of the letter S resulting in the top edge of the `tikzpicture` being vertically aligned with the top of the first row of text in the left column:

[image]

Here is the full MWE, in which I also tried my best to get rid of the deprecated `\tikzstyle` as well as repeated settings (I used a new `common` style for that)

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta}


\tikzset{common/.style=     {minimum width=3cm, 
                             minimum height=1cm,
                             text centered, 
                             draw=black},
         startstop/.style = {common, 
                             rectangle, 
                             rounded corners, 
                             fill=red!30},
         io/.style =        {common, 
                             trapezium,
                             trapezium left angle=70, 
                             trapezium right angle=110, 
                             rounded corners, 
                             fill=blue!30},
          process/.style =  {common, 
                             rectangle, 
                             fill=orange!30},
          decision/.style = {common, 
                             diamond, 
                             fill=green!30},
          arrow/.style=     {thick,
                             ->,
                             >=stealth}
          }
   
\newlength{\mylength}       
\settoheight{\mylength}{S}
              
\begin{document}
    \subsection{Flowchart}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{6cm}|p{6cm}|  }
        \hline
        Algorithm & Flowchart\\
        \hline
        Stuff 
        
        more
        
        stuff
        & 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, baseline={([yshift=-\mylength]current bounding box.north)}]
        \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
        \node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Input};
        \node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {Loop start};
        \node (pro2) [process, below of=pro1] {Process 1};
        \node (pro3) [process, below of=pro2] {Process 1};
        \node (dec1) [decision, below of=pro3] {Decision 1};
        
        \draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
        \draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
        \draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (pro2);
        \draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro3);
        \draw [arrow] (pro3) -- (dec1);
        
        \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=north] {Yes} ([xshift=7mm] dec1.east) -- ([xshift=7mm] pro1.east) -- (pro1);
        \end{tikzpicture} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using my (accepted) answer on your previous question and `tabularx` table environment for table. For align of algorithm and flowchart at the top cells it is sufficient to add option `baseline` to `tikzpicture`.

In MWE below is added `makacell` package for additional vertical space around cells contents and for the `\thead` command` for column headers::

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for generating dummy text

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |L|C|  }
    \hline
\thead{Algorithm}       
            &   \thead{Flowchart}           \\
    \hline
\lipsum[66] &   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, % <---
            node distance = 6mm and 18mm,
              start chain = A going below,
        %
           arr/.style = {-Straight Barb, semithick},
          base/.style = {draw, minimum width=32mm, minimum height=8mm,
                         align=center, on chain=A, join=by arr},
        startstop/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=red!30},   % <---
          process/.style = {base, fill=orange!30},                 % <---
               io/.style = {base, trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                            trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                            fill=blue!30},
         decision/.style = {base, diamond, fill=green!30},
        every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, font=\small}
                            ]
        \node [startstop]       {input};            % <-- A-1
        \node [process]         {Loop start};
        \node [process]         {1};
        \node [process]         {2};
        \node [decision]        {Yes or No ?};
        \node [startstop]       {Stop};              % <-- A-6
        %%
        \draw[arr]  (A-5.west)  to ["No"] ++ (-1.8,0) |- (A-2);
        \path       (A-5)       to ["Yes"]  (A-6);
                    \end{tikzpicture}       \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]